# Lead width range for motor driver IC

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, dc-motor, motor-controller, chip-design

I am creating a footprint for [this part](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/nxp-usa-inc/MC33931VWR2/2185658) in Altium. I was able to get all the dimensions, but can't seem to figure out the lead width range as shown in this diagram:

[image]

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure it out.

Here are the two relevant pages with the mechanical information:

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, these are pages 17 and 18 in the [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MC33931.pdf).

Comment: It's not that important. You know the pitch and you should have some idea of how much space you need between the edges of pads. That's pretty much all you need because the pads don't have to be the *exact* size of the pins and you would actually have problems if they were.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand section W-W correctly, the range of lead width is 0.220 mm to 0.350 mm. Someone more knowledgeable in GD&T might correct me.
[image]